# How to see the "queryDebugString" on MongoDB's Text Search?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying the Text Search functionality from MongoDB, and out there on the internet I can see lots of information where people do this:

```
db.posts.runCommand("text", {search: '"robots are crazy"'})
```

And get this:

```
{
    "queryDebugString" : "robot||||robots are||",
    "language" : "english",
    "results" : [
        {
            "score" : 0.6666666666666666,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ebc482214a1e88aaa4ad9e"),
                "txt" : "Robots are superior to humans"
            }
        }
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "n" : 1,
        "timeMicros" : 185
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I know `runCommand("text", ...` is deprecated, but I've tried the `db.posts.find({ $text: { $search: '"robots are crazy"' } })` approach as well, and nothing there.

How can I see this "queryDebugString" attribute? I've looked for some kind of debug flags to use when starting up mongod, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more recent versions of Mongo (2.6 at least), use `.explain(true)` for the verbose output, which will contain a `parsedTextQuery` field with more, and more readable, information than `queryDebugString`:

```
> db.test.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "cows are lovely" } }).explain(true)
{
    "cursor" : "TextCursor",
    ...
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "TEXT",
        ...
        "parsedTextQuery" : {
            "terms" : ["cow", "love"],
            "negatedTerms" : [],
            "phrases" : [],
            "negatedPhrases" : []
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try this:

```
db.posts.find({ "text" : '"robots are crazy"' })
```

Now in Mongo, operations became (in basic state) something like:

```
db.collection.action({query}}
```

I think it's enough to start, but try to go to the MongoDB documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/